# Is there any "after" page loaded hook for capybara+rspec

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I am using capybara and rspec for my test automation and have search for how to assert if text exist in the page every time a new page loaded.

Example.
Visit Home page
Assert "Benjie" is in page
Click link
wait for page to load
Assert "Benjie" is in page

Is there anyway I can do that without typing each assert manually?

Comment: I would question how useful your test is in the first place if you need to assert for the same identical text over and over with each page load.

Comment: If you have a system that is customizable and clients will usually have their branding or own words in the system

Comment: @BenjieSejas that looks more like view specs than an integration spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Capybara doesn't have a hook to run code after every page change.  In fact, Capybara doesn't actually know when the page changes other than when you call `visit`.  Every other behavior is assumed to be asynchronous.